# Calculate transformation for obtaining bounding box in perspective view

Tags: opengl, 3d, point-cloud-library, perspectivecamera

This problem does not completely depend on [point cloud library](http://pointclouds.org). Instead, it is a computer graphics problem.

Given a perspective view of a scene which contains a ball, we need to obtain bounding box of this ball. Please see a sample figure below-

[image: sample figure showing perspective view]

If the yellow ball is projected, a  bounding rectangle can be defined by two diagonal points `s1` and `s2`. 3D coordinates of these points were defined by the following procedure-

1. Visualize the point cloud in [PCLVisualizer](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html)
2. Define 2D bounding box using two diagonal points specifically for this view and get the 3D coordinates of the points using [registerPointPickingCallback()](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#a2f57c96f368bb8e41dc65e8528ac9325) callback function
3. Define minimum and maximum `x`, `y` coordinates by comparing diagonal points
4. Define minimum and maximum z coordinate based on the experimental setup

From the above procedure, 3D coordinates of `s1` and `s2` were found as shown below.

```
Point s1: (0.774406, 0.295306, 2.703) 
Point s2: ( 1.37865, 0.845276, 2.834)
```

By comparing `s1` and `s2`, a box was defined and [addCube](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#a6e4d4cf26e3a97aad4d86b49ed865dd1) was used but it didn't work. See two screenshots of the output below taken at different camera angles-

[image: output of box filter]

Below is the code snippet-

```
double x_min = 0.774406, x_max = 1.37865;
double y_min = 0.295306, y_max = 0.845276;
double z_min = 0.2,      z_max = 3.0;

pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Cloud Viewer");
viewer.setCameraParameters(camera);
viewer.addCube(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, z_min, z_max, 1, 0, 0, "bounding_box");
```

Fortunately, [addCube](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#a6e805f7508dcefb2cf6fa3eb817c1432) function has another definition, which provides a way to apply translation and rotation.

**My question is, using these two points i.e., `s1` and `s2`, and [camera](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_camera.html), how do define the transformations, so that the bounding box contains the ball.**

Below are the links to download all required file, in order to run the project-

1. [bounding_box.cpp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4tykh6e3jrpih7/bounding_box.cpp?dl=0): The CPP file
2. [scene.pcd](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ws29rnowzll075t/scene.pcd?dl=0): The captured PCD file used in above CPP code
3. [camera.cam](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue5yq3nmpardxal/camera.cam?dl=0): Camera file used in above CPP code

*Dependency: PCL 1.8*

Comment: You need to re-compute the bounding box in camera space, by approximating the ball as an ellipsoid bounded by the box `s1, s2` in world space. There is no way to directly transform (or "rotate") the box without it rescaling somehow.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Thank you very much! (1) `computeViewMatrix` didn't work. (2) I am sorry, I didn't get your point. If you see the [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzfcU.jpg), you can notice that ball is surrounded by `s1` and `s2`. But once I rotated the view, the reality comes into the picture. By the way, I have added 2D and 3D coordinates of `s1`  and `s2`.

Comment: Yes I did realize that `computeViewMatrix` wasn't going to work by itself. Are `s1, s2` in *world* space or camera space? If they're in world space there is no reason why it should not work. If it is camera space then you need the view matrix.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Yes. `s1` and `s2` are in world coordinate system. Well, just being more clear that my overall goal is to get the 3D space which encloses the ball.

Comment: Then I see no reason why this would not work - unless either the coordinates are incorrect or the box filter's transformation was not identity.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: I shared complete code and project files such as point cloud file etc in the updated question above. Please have a look. The coordinates are reported by PCL library. I visualized them by plotting. It looks fine. I am not sure about the transformation matrix though!

Comment: Why are `z_min, z_max` different to the values of `s1, s2`?

Comment: The `z` axis is pointing outside from the front of the sensor. The sensor detects objects kept more than 0.5 m up to 5 m. However in this situation, the ball is less than 3 m away from the sensor. So the maximum possible limits for the `z` axis is 0.2 to 3.0 m.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Any comments or suggestions, please?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the given values of `s1, s2` are correct? Better to examine the PCD file for confirmation. No reason why a trivial world-space crop wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169520/discussion-between-ravi-joshi-and-meowgoesthedog).

Comment: any suggestions, please!